# transaction with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, transactions

I am new to Postgresql and I try to do something so simple with Oracle.

I created a procedure with a simple code inside :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE user.test_proc(IN param1 character varying)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS $BODY$
DECLARE
   i text;
BEGIN

   if param1 = '1' then
     insert into amian.test values ('1', '1');
     rollback;
   else
      insert into amian.test values('2','2');
      commit;
   end if;
end;
$BODY$;
```

From unix environement I use psql :

```
psql –p port–d base–U user
\set AUTOCOMMIT off
call user.test_proc('2');
```

I have this error when the programm meets the COMMIT :

```
invalid transaction termination
```

What is wrong ? what should I do (I want to be with autocommit off) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use `COMMIT` and `ROLLBACK` in a procedure if the procedure is running in its own transaction (autocommit mode). See this quote from [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-call.html):

> If `CALL` is executed in a transaction block, then the called procedure cannot execute transaction control statements. Transaction control statements are only allowed if `CALL` is executed in its own transaction.

Turning off autocommit in `psql` causes the client to send a `BEGIN` before the `CALL` statement, so you are in an explicitly started transaction. That causes the problem.

This restriction may be lifted at some point in the future, but currently that's the way it is.

Don't disable autocommit. You are risking long transactions, which can impair the health of your database.

Comment: So, what you say is that somehow this is a postgresql bug. That I have to leave set autocommit on and take the risk that some queries (insert or update) are committed though I dont want to because I would forget a commit which endangers the database ?

Comment: That is not a PostGreSQL bug. That is a limitation of PG functionnality like many others: nested transactions, read uncommitted, DDL transactions... Read the paper I wrote about lack of functionnalities... http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-sql-server-mssql-part-3-very-extremely-detailed-comparison/,

Comment: @mlwacosmos It is not a bug, it is working as documented (see my added quotation). Sorry if you don't like it.